# Recover temporary files create during a Word session

Tags: microsoft-word, recycle-bin

I was in the middle of creating a document when Microsoft Word crashed. When I restarted, it asked me what I wanted to do with some temporary file, to which I answered delete. But unfortunately it was the latest version of my document, and I am now left with just a few lines in the beginning. Is there a way I can get my old file or have I dug my own grave?

Also, I can't find the recycle bin on my desktop. I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, I can't find the recycle bin on my desktop.

Open [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) (<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) and select `C:\`. You'll see a Recycle Bin, and this will show deleted files for all drives.

But, depending how an application deletes a file, it might be immediately deleted permanently, not moved to the recycle bin.

Comment: cant see the recycle bi as you mentioned:-(

Comment: Right click on the desktop, select properties and one of the tabs should allow you to select certain system icons on the desktop (don't have WinXP currently running for a quick check on tab names). NB. in a corporate environment these things can be locked out.

Comment: already checked that ,there is no mention of recycle bin apart from some option to change its icon.May be its the corporate stuff you mentioned.its my office system.